# ad-killer Chrome extension corruption and can't connect to VPN

Tags: google-chrome

Today, my add-killer Chrome extension said it was corrupted. I don't remember the name of the extension. I installed about 2 years ago. I searched for ad blocker and installed the first extension that appeared there. I'm not sure if the extension is now removed from the App Store? The extension said it was corrupted, and I had to click to fix it. I clicked and I don't think this was a good idea.

After that I cannot get to my company intranet after VPN connection. I get `502 Bad Gateway`. I'm using Cisco Any Connect.

Troubleshooting:

- Clear cache, cookies, history.
- Reinstall Cisco AnyConnect.
- Tried another browser. Safari works.
- I can browse other websites.
- I uninstalled Chrome and installed it again.

I wonder if this is some sort of malware.

Environment:

- Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client: Version 4.4.01054
- OS: macOS Sierra
- Google Chrome is up to date
- Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Model Name:  MacBook Pro
- Model Identifier:    MacBookPro14,3
- Processor Name:  Intel Core i7
- Processor Speed: 3.1 GHz
- Number of Processors:    1
- Total Number of Cores:   4
- L2 Cache (per Core): 256 KB
- L3 Cache:    8 MB
- Memory:  16 GB
- Boot ROM Version:    MBP143.0160.B02
- SMC Version (system):    2.45f0
- Serial Number (system):  C02TW0T6HTDG
- Hardware UUID:   61C280BC-C0D6-5946-A9CA-8967E11AAD8D

Comment: There is no such Chrome extension as ad-killer or add-killer. What do you mean? Maybe Ads Killer, I don't know.

Comment: @karel hmmm, I tried to find it now and don't see it????

Comment: I don't even know if this Chrome extension is malware or not.

Comment: @karel To tell you the truth, I don't remember the name of the extension.  I installed about 2 years ago.  I searched for ad blocker and installed the first extension that appeared there.  Not sure if the extension is now removed from the App Store???

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this happens to somebody else.  The solution is to uninstall of the extensions and add only the extensions you really need.

This is a NASTY Chrome bug in my opinion, but I don't a trace or any kind of logs to help debug this issue.